# Embed StreetViewPanorama in google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, closures

I'm trying to embed a street view panorama in google maps marker infowindow (popup). The problem is that when I click in the marker, it only changes the content of the streetViewPanorama. Otherwise the text content is the same for every marker.

See the click listener in the following code or see the problem in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oyge1huj/.

```
var content = '<div id="content-wrapper">' +
    '<div class="title"><h2>' + markers[i][0] + '</h2></div>' +
    '<div class="separator"></div>' +
    '<p><label><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Address: </label>' + markers[i][1] + '</p>' +
    '<p><label><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone: </label>' + markers[i][2] + '</p>' +
    '<p><label><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>GPS: </label>' + markers[i][4] + ', ' + markers[i][3] + '</p>' +
    '</div>';

var infoWindowContent = document.createElement("div");

infoWindowContent.setAttribute("id", "content");
infoWindowContent.innerHTML = content;

var streetview = document.createElement("div");

streetview.setAttribute("id", "street");
streetview.style.width = "100%";
streetview.style.height = "100px";

infoWindowContent.appendChild(streetview);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoWindowContent
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content, infowindow) {
    return function () {
        // infowindow.setContent(content);
        openInfoWindow(marker);
    };
})(marker, content, infowindow));

function openInfoWindow(marker) {
    pin.set("position", marker.getPosition());
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    //map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}

var panorama = null;
var pin = new google.maps.MVCObject();

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, "domready", function () {
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(streetview, {
        navigationControl: false,
        enableCloseButton: false,
        addressControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        linksControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        visible: true
    });
    panorama.bindTo("position", pin);
});
```

Comment: You are looping through your markers and redefine `var content` each time so it will only keep the last values (seventh shop). You commented the `infowindow.setContent(content);` but this is the way to go. Just make sure the content is the appropriate one (maybe you could build your content within the click event listener).

Comment: @MrUpsidown try what you said, if you remove the comment of infowindow.setContent(content); the streetViewPanorama only will work in one marker.

Comment: I didn't say that it would work if you just uncomment that line. That said, what have you tried?

Comment: I've uncommented that line but when I click in the marker, it only opens infowindow to one marker.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_StreetViewInInfoWindowB.html